# New to NGINX. How do I add this line to my conf file(s)?

Tags: nginx

I'm sorry if this question is obvious but I've been searching and getting nowhere. I'm hosting a small server program called Wallabag but I've been having a small problem with its sessions being too short. I found a helpful guide here http://doc.wallabag.org/en/Administrator/sessions.html and everything works except this last line here:

> If you're using nginx, add 
>   `php_admin_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/wallabag-session`
>   in your nginx configuration file. Then, restart

For the life of me I can't figure out where to add this line without nginx throwing up an error. Where in the default file would this line go? I've looked everywhere to no avail. Everything that's more direct is dealing with apache rather than ngnix.

Some other links I found:

[This](https://github.com/wallabag/wallabag/issues/769) topic on this specific issue from before the wiki guide was made. Only one person had nginx and their setup is different since they're using php-fpm

Comment: Yeah I hit enter by accident on my phone. I finished it up but I'll make the formatting better on my computer in a moment

Comment: I think they're referring to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  Try adding it inside the `http {}` code block.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to reply until today. I tried it right under the beginning of the `http {}` block and got this error upon restarting it `Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "php_admin_value[session.save_path]" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:16
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` I'm not sure what I should do now. Php is installed that I'm sure of.